# How to make a SOAP call with dot42?

Tags: dot42

I have the following code.  I know that the webrequests and such should be in async calls but I just wanted proof of concept.

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Os;
using Android.Widget;
using Dot42;
using Dot42.Manifest;
using System.Xml;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

[assembly: Application("dot42Application6")]

namespace dot42Application6
{
    [Activity]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstance)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstance);
        SetContentView(R.Layouts.MainLayout);
        string soap = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
        <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" 
        xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" 
        xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">
        <soap:Body><GetColorChangeCharge xmlns=""http://reps.catalystinnovations.net/"">
        <password>ujnvusk</password></GetColorChangeCharge></soap:Body>    </soap:Envelope>";

        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.someurl/service.asmx");
        req.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "http://www.someurl/GetColorChangeCharge");
        req.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=utf-8";
        req.Accept = "text/xml";
        req.Method = "POST";

        using (Stream stm = req.GetRequestStream())
        {
            using (StreamWriter stmw = new StreamWriter(stm))
            {
                stmw.Write(soap);
            }
        }

        WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
        Stream responsStream = resp.GetResponseStream();

    }


}
```

}

I get a java.lang.Runtime exception at 
   WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
I have no idea what the problem is or how to fix it.